# Error: Boot Image download from platform builder (Windows Embedded Compact 7)

Tags: embedded, windows-virtual-pc

Why is it that my windows virtual PC device is sending BOOTME Message but my platform builder is still waiting for download request from device? Is there something that I need to configure? Please see image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Found out the problem ...
BOOTME messages were blocked by my Windows FireWwll. easiest way to solve problem is to disable the firewall or create an "allow" rule.

Comment: Found the problem! BOOTME messages were blocked by trend micro antivirus! :)

Comment: Can you show which application in the firewall that is needs to be allowed? Is it the platform builder service? A screenshot would be helpful.